# Other computer on the same intranet can't connect to my web server on my virtual machine

Tags: vagrant, virtual

I used vagrant to setup a virtual machine and then on that virtual machine, I set up a webserver with ip I config like below:

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.12"
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.33.13"
  config.vm.network :public_network
```

And I connected successfully to my web server on my computer via this IP 192.168.33.12 but then I tried to use other computer on the same network, I couldn't connect to it (192.168.33.13 neither)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your virtual machine missed default gateway for your network.
Try adding your LAN default gateway to the virtual machine.

```
 ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost

 sudo route add default gw 192.168.33.254
```

where 192.168.33.254 has to be change with correct default gateway.